# Laravel Eloquent Relationships - 3 tables, one of which is a lookup table

Tags: laravel, eloquent, relationships

I am struggling to get my head around some relationships.

1. I have a Model called User (just stores Users)
2. A model called Addresses (stores all the addresses a user might have)
3. A model called Countries (a lookup list of country codes and descriptions)

Below are simplified schema's to help show you what I am trying to achieve:

User model

```
user_id (integer)
```

Address Table

```
user_id (integer)
country_code (integer)
```

Countries table:

```
country_code (integer)
country_description (text)
```

I had a relationship in the User model as follows:
The user model has a relationship:

```
public function addresses() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Address');
}
```

In the Address model I have a relationship of

```
public function user() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}
```

Now, in my blade template I am able to @foreach through user->addresses and return the country code stored in the address table, such as 'US' or 'GB'

However, I want to be able to display the full country name, which is held in the Countries table.

How and where do I setup a relationship which will still allow me to iterate through the addresses table, but also have a relationship with the Countries table so that I can display the countries->country_description column.?

Any ideas

Regards

James

Comment: Not tested, but try adding this in your `Addresses` model: `public function country() { return $this->belongsTo('App\Countries', 'country_code'); }`. Then, when you loop through a user's addresses: `$address->country->country_description`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your Address Model:

```
public function countries()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Countries', 'country_code');
}
```

You could then access an $address->countries->country_description;

Comment: Thanks, this worked - it was how to access it in the blade.page which I was getting wrong, so your $address->countries->country_description fixed this. I didn't know it was possible to chain like that. Thanks again!

Comment: See more of that here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships